# Which button was clicked?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

How can I detect which mouse button was clicked (right or left)
in the slot for QtCore.SIGNAL('cellClicked(int,int)')?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably pass the event to your `cellClicked` function.  I'm assuming you emit your signal from a place that has access to a QMouseEvent.

Check out [this thread](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2009-March/022225.html).

Excerpt:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
        event.accept()
        self.rightClickMenu(event)
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

Also, [this mailing list thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg16739.html) looks like a more complete example.